# how to compare to two json files and return a un matched key and value in object

Tags: python-3.x

#### JSON File1:

```
 [{
    "App_Name": "Test1",
    "Instances": "2",
    "Memory": "2G",
    "Disk_Quota": "1G"
}, {
    "App_Name": "Test2",
    "Instances": "2",
    "Memory": "2G",
    "Disk_Quota": "1G"
}, {
    "App_Name": "Test3",
    "Instances": "1",
    "Memory": "1G",
    "Disk_Quota": "1G"
}]
```

#### JSON file2:

```
 [ {
    "App_Name": "Test3",
    "Instances": "1",
    "Memory": "1G",
    "Disk_Quota": "5G"
 },{
    "App_Name": "Test1",
    "Instances": "3",
    "Memory": "2G",
    "Disk_Quota": "1G"
}, {
    "App_Name": "Test2",
    "Instances": "2",
    "Memory": "8G",
    "Disk_Quota": "1G"
}]
```

I have to compare both the JSON files and need to print the unmatched value from the JSON objects.

So far I have tried this one

```
def Compare():

    with open("Jsonfile1.json") as f:
        data = f.read()
        env1 = json.loads(data)

    with open("jsonfile2.json") as f:
        data = f.read()
        env2 = json.loads(data)



    for name in env1:
            for names in env2:
                if name['App_Name'] == names['App_Name']:
                    if name['Instances'] != names['Instances']:
                        print("unmatched val {} -i {}".format(name['App_Name'],names['Instances']))
                        if name['Memory'] != names['Memory']:
                            # print(name['Memory'], names['Memory'])
                            print("unmatched val {} -m {}".format(name['App_Name'],names['Memory']))
                            if name['Disk_Quota'] != names['Disk_Quota']:
                                print("unmatched val {} -k {}".format(name['App_Name'],names['Disk_Quota']))

Compare()
```

Excepted output :

if there is a mismatch in instance then print(jsonfile1 instance value)
if there is a mismatch in memory then print(jsonfile1 memory value)
if there is a mismatch in disk then print(jsonfile1 disk value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
for d1 in env1:  # Iterate over all dictionaries in first JSON
    # Look for the corresponding dictionary in second JSON
    candidates = [d for d in env2 if d["App_Name"] == d1["App_Name"]]
    if not candidates:
        print(d1)  # If no corresponding dict, just print and go to next
    else:
        d2 = candidates[0]  # If corresponding dict, look for mismatches
        for key in d1:
            if d1.get(key) != d2.get(key):  # Find mismatches
                print(f"mismatch detected for app='{d1['App_Name']}'")
                print(f"\tenv1's value for key='{key}' is {d1.get(key)}")
                print(f"\twhile env2's value for key='{key}' is {d2.get(key)}")
```

Output:

```
mismatch detected for app='Test1'
    env1's value for key='Instances' is 2
    while env2's value for key='Instances' is 3
mismatch detected for app='Test2'
    env1's value for key='Memory' is 2G
    while env2's value for key='Memory' is 8G
mismatch detected for app='Test3'
    env1's value for key='Disk_Quota' is 1G
    while env2's value for key='Disk_Quota' is 5G
```

Comment: The two JSON files are not in the same format.  [ {
    "App_Name": "Test3",
    "Instances": "1",
    "Memory": "1G",
    "Disk_Quota": "5G"
 },{
    "App_Name": "Test1",
    "Instances": "3",
    "Memory": "2G",
    "Disk_Quota": "1G"
}, {
    "App_Name": "Test2",
    "Instances": "2",
    "Memory": "8G",
    "Disk_Quota": "1G"
}]

Comment: Thanks. But I need to compare In Json file1, the first object app name is to compare with all objects in second JSON file and has to return the unmatched value

Comment: That's not clear from your question, as your code asks for `if name['App_Name'] == names['App_Name']:`, assuming that only objects with same app names have to be compared. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: I have to take first object app name in json file1 and have to iterate all objects in second JSON file and find the matched app name and compare the instances, memory, disk and print unmatched key- value.

Comment: Thanks @Arnaud. It would be great if i give me a little more on this. If the app name is not present in second json just return entire object and iterate for remaining objects.

Comment: Updated. Please, that's the last update, otherwise this is never ending - if further things then a new question may be needed.

Comment: can we do vice versa comparison for the above two files?. Now we comparing env1 to env2. I need to compare env2 to env1 as well or vice versa.